# Java Programming error

Tags: java

My two classes are listed below: the TennisTeam class and the TennisTeamApp class which uses it. There is an error which is:

```
Player cannot be resolved to a type
```

Please can someone tell me how to fix that?

```
// Kartik Patel
// 16/08/2013

  public class TennisTeam{
  private String country;
  public Player player1;
  public Player player2;

//  Constructor
  public TennisTeam(String countryIn){
    country = countryIn;
    storePlayerData(country);
  }

//  Gets and stores user name 
  public void storePlayerData(String country){
   String prompt = "Enter Players Name ";
   System.out.println("Getting data from country " + country);
   System.out.println("Player 1, " + country +": ");
   System.out.println(readString(prompt));
   System.out.println("Player 2, " + country + ": ");
   System.out.println(readString(prompt));
  }

//  Read Strings
  public String readString (String prompt){
    java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(prompt);
    return keyboard.nextLine();
  }

//  Assessors returning values
  public String getCountry(){
   return country; 
  }
}



public class TennisTeamApp{
  public ststic void main(String [] args){
    TennisTeam [ ] teams = { new TennisTeam("NZ"), new TennisTeam("AUS")};

    for (TennisTeam team: teams){
      System.out.println(team.getCountry() + ": ");
      System.out.println(team.player1.getName() + ", ");
       System.out.println(team.player2.getName());
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is the `Player` class in the same package? If not, did you import it?

Comment: It looks like its complaining that you haven't defined what a `Player` is. If you do have a Player source file, post its contents. If not, that's your problem.

Comment: It looks like you are using Eclipse. If you want to use a class from another class, you must put both classes in a package. Then, you need to import the other class (unless it is in the same package).

Comment: You're not instantiating players anywhere.

Comment: what you mean by a source file

Comment: @user2669883 Where is the file that defines what a `Player` is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I got " cannot be resolved to a type" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579558/why-i-got-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-error)

Comment: @user2669883 you cannot have two public classes in the same .java file. So you must have defined two classes in two separate files. The files in which Player class is referenced must import the Player class before referencing it. IDE should do it on it's own is it's in the same project. If you are using command line then add an import Player.java statement.

Answer (score 4):

Import `Player` with an import statement. The reason `Player` is not resolved to a type is because it's not known in the namespaces available, so the fix is to import it.

Comment: Use the import keyword. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: @user2669883 Look it up in the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial).

Comment: They're not downvoting because you're wrong, but because you gave a five word answer with unclear pronouns.

Comment: @Chris Bode: I see, didn't think it could be unclear, but I see now, thanks for clearing that up. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not shared the `Player` class which need to be there in order to compile your `TennisTeam` class as it holds a reference to `Player`. So make sure you have a compiled `Player` class before you try to compiler your `TennisTeam` class. If it is there then make sure you have imported it in your TennisTeam class.

Another problem in your code is that you have not initialized your Player objects while initializing your TennisTeam object. Hence you will run into Null pointer exception while accesing the player object in line:

```
  System.out.println(team.player1.getName() + ", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Kartik,

For some reason I love doing beginners-level homework problems so well that if you (the OP) are silly enough to pass it off as your own work then you'll be caught cheating for sure (unless your teacher is completely incompetent), while still giving you some *useful* guidance. I guess I'm just another smartass at heart... but a marginally useful one.

Sooo without any further ado...

*The **Player** class: (the one that is/was MIA)*

```
package forums.kartikPatel.tennis;

public class Player {
    private final String name;
    Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

This is an immutable data transfer object. "Immutable" is fancy-pants term for "read only". Meaning that once the object has been created (once the Constructor has completed) it cannot be changed. A "data transfer object" is exactly what it's name entails: an object that exists SOLELY to transfer the data that represents something around between other classes which actually "do stuff" with/to that data. It does not (and should not) have any "smarts"... transfer objects should be as simple (as stupid) as possible.

*Here's my version of the **Team** class:*

```
package forums.kartikPatel.tennis;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Team implements Iterable<Player> {

    private final String country;
    private final List<Player> players;

    public Team(String country) {
        this.country = country;
        this.players = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
        players.add(player);
    }

    public Player getPlayer(int index) {
        return players.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Player> iterator() {
        return players.iterator();
    }
}
```

The Team class is another data transfer object. It exists SOLELY to keep all the information that we want to store about a tennis team together in one place. This version works with teams of any number of players, which is good in that we handle teams of three players without changing the software, but in this version it will also accept teams of no players... and I haven't yet seen that in the real world (but hey, if the Kiwis play the team of no-bodies at-least they're in with a even chance, which is a nice change for them), so our software probably shouldn't allow the user to do that, so as a challenge try fixing things (no, the software, not the Kiwis) so that at-least one player is required when populating each team... that or print an "Empty Team!" error message when we come to print-out the line-ups.

I made the Team implement Iterable because it makes sense to view a team as "a bunch of players, from a country" and Iterable allows us to do just that in the *Application* class, which is coming right up.

*The **Application** class:*

```
package forums.kartikPatel.tennis;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application
{
    private static final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static final PrintStream screen = System.out;

    public void run() {
        // create two new teams: New Zealand (BOO!) and Australia (YEAH!)
        Team[] teams = {new Team("NZ"), new Team("AUS")};
        // populate both teams with players
        populate(teams);
        // display both teams, and all there players.
        display(teams);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // input

    // populate both teams with players
    private void populate(Team[] teams) {
        for ( Team team : teams ) {
            screen.println("Please enter the players for: " + team.getCountry());
            for (String name=readPlayersName(); name.length()>0; name=readPlayersName())
                team.addPlayer(new Player(name));
            screen.println();
        }
    }
    private String readPlayersName() {
        return readString("Players Name: ");
    }
    private String readString(String prompt) {
        screen.print(prompt);
        return keyboard.nextLine();
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // output

    // display both teams, and all there players.
    private void display(Team[] teams) {
        screen.println("The line-ups are:");
        for ( Team team : teams ) {
            System.out.print(team.getCountry() + ": ");
            for ( Player player : team )
                screen.print(player.getName() + ", ");
            screen.println();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is a "traditional" console Application. When you *run* the *tennis.Application* it uses a *screen* and a *keyboard* to create, *populate*, and *display* two *teams* of *players*. It contains all the code that actually "does stuff" in this rather simple application. However if/when the two teams get around to actually playing a tennis match I expect we would want a separate class (probably several) to implement playing the game itself... Hell even just keeping the score might involve a Scorer, some Scores, a DueceHelper, and a large box of pine-apples (or possibly NOT).

What the application class does NOT do is "remember stuff"... well not directly. It creates and uses "transfer objects" which "remember stuff".

It's also worth noting that you will see the same three basic steps in all types of applications:

1. Input,
2. processing, and
3. output.

So making these basic steps manifest (ie explicit) in your code is a good idea, especially for a beginner, as it helps you focus on the problem that you need to solve here-and-how... and not get muddled up with the problems that you shouldn't be trying to solve in this method/class/module/subsystem/application... like trying to find a large bread knife to open the box to get the pineapple to beat the ref over the head with during the gentile exchange of opinions over a dodgy line-call ending a tense Love-all in the decider of the third set... Obviously, you should have prepared your ammunition earlier, or just throw the whole frickin box at him and hope his eye-sight improves before the end of the match.

The point is to design each class to fulfill a well-defined set of responsibilities. Each class shall contain methods with simple, understandable names, and indeed each method shall implements a simple, understandable task. This is the essence of good program design. Keeping things as simple-as-possible helps reduce bugs (errors) buy minimising misunderstandings. It also helps make your software flexibly and reusable, which means that it's easier to maintain... to adapt to currently unforseeable future requirements... which all helps reduce the cost of software ownership in the long term, meaning you can charge less than your competitors to do less work which does more good... and that's all good.

*And finally my **Main** class:*

```
package forums;

import forums.kartikPatel.tennis.Application;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().run();
    }
}
```

The Main class has one responsibility: To *run* the *Application*.

*Doing so produces something like the following output (depending on what you input, obviousy):*

```
    Please enter the players for: NZ
    Players Name: Bob The Builder
    Players Name: Kania Fixit
    Players Name: Yazzie Can
    Players Name: 

    Please enter the players for: AUS
    Players Name: Mark Horran
    Players Name: Blocka Roach
    Players Name: The Reverand Fred Effing Nile
    Players Name: 

    The line-ups are:
    NZ: Bob The Builder, Kania Fixit, Yazzie Can, 
    AUS: Mark Horran, Blocka Roach, The Reverand Fred Effing Nile,
```

As another challenge, try getting-rid of that alloying trailing comma after the last name in each team. Hint: Think "the comma preceeds each subsequent item" instead of the traditional (more obvious) thinking that the comma follows each item except the last one... the trick of course being that it's hard to know when you're dealing with the ultimate item, but you can easily determine if/when you're processing the first (as apposed to subsequent) item of a list.

I hope this helps somewhat. You're doing fine for a beginner. Keep trying and you'll soon understand more than me... it's not hard. I was outsmarted by a fish once... long story ;-)

Cheers. Keith.