# Trying to work on a new project but facing problems with the JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, development-environment, facet

Currently I am trying to use Java SE 1.8 as the build path JRE and the project facet. However I seem to be getting the error as shown below:

[image]

Now here is the error I get when I select Java 1.8 as the execution environment:

[image: problem]

If I change the project facet and the execution environment to 1.7, I get bombarded with these errors as shown below:

[image]

Comment: *"I get bombarded with these errors"* - this is what you should be happy with. Your javac started working and validating your project just fine. Probably there is a problem with your packages, that is why some classes cannot be found. Fix that one and you will be ok.

Comment: Do you have a Java 8 JRE/JDK shown in Preferences > Java > Installed JREs? If not you need to add one.

Comment: @greg-449 how do you install a specific JRE for elipse?

Comment: No, but you have to tell Eclipse where to look for the JRE/JDK. You have to have a Java 8 JRE/JDK installed somewhere to use Java 8 (and Eclipse Luna or Mars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From Screenshot 2 and 3, I can conclude following-

1. You don't have JRE 8 Configured. For JRE Configuration refer [Stakoverflow-Configure JRE In Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394822/setting-up-eclipse-with-jre-path)
2. You're getting Type resolving issues. This means either you need project cleanup or you're missing package declaration. Refer this-[Why I got cannot be resolved to type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579558/why-i-got-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-error)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by giving right path of the `JRE` to the `eclipse`.